# Do all these maps & comprehensions do the same thing? Which are more Pythonic?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mapping, list-comprehension

Starting with this:

```
from itertools import repeat

def numin(srch_string, memlist):
    return srch_string.count(memlist)

sublist = ('x', 'str', 'a', 'pr')
string = "rprpraxp"
```

I'm coming up with ways to find the total instances of the members of the sublist in the given string (which in this case happens to be 4)

I've dorked around with it and come up with these four approaches:

```
inst = 0
for member in sublist:
    inst = inst + numin(string, member)
print(inst)
```

and

```
print(sum(numin(string, member) for member in sublist))
```

and

```
print(sum(map(lambda member: numin(string, member), sublist)))
```

and

```
print(sum(map(numin, repeat(string), sublist)))
```

To the best of my amateur knowledge, each of these four work, and do the same thing. What are the considerations for opting for one of these over the others?

Thanks.

PS. I am specifically excluding solutions that don't access the function numin() for the purpose of this exploration.

EDIT: Edited out pointless call to LIST.

Comment: The call to `list()` is unnecessary in all cases.

Comment: `sum(numin(string, member) for member in sublist)` is what I would do.

Comment: you are correct, list is pointless, my goof.

Comment: Use `sum(numin(string, member) for member in sublist)`.  That is the most efficient and it's also very clear.

Comment: Another approach is to use [higher-order functions](https://gist.github.com/juanarrivillaga/883029c6c01648f4017e5a658b96cd77) . Although, in this *particular* case, you don't even need that! Just pass the bound-method: `sum(map(string.count, sublist))`.

Comment: Very interesting, thank you.

Comment: If you must use `numin`, then  juanpa's 1st solution is best, otherwise use his last solution. BTW, as a general rule, use `map` with functions that run at C speed (like built-in functions, and many standard library functions) rather than Python functions, including `lambda`s. An alternative to your `lambda member: numin(string, member)` would be to use a `partial` object created using `functools.partial`, but I don't know how much more efficient it is than a `lambda` / `def` function.